# Unable to add in app products in google play console suddenly ( Please check the list below for problems. )

Tags: google-play, android-inapp-purchase

My app was published about 4-5 months ago. My in-app products works fine. Suddenly I am unable to add or edit new in-app products. It shows me error **"Please check the list below for problems."**, but there is no problem in the list. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: I have the same problem. Didn't find any workaround, hope it will start working soon.

Comment: at the same time i am facing verify purchase failed :(

Comment: same, raised a bug on google console

Comment: Did you solve your problem for subscription ? I'm currently stuck on that :/

Comment: i was facing the same issue, I see the new country added in list. so set the price of the new added country.

Answer (score 3):

I did experience this issue since yesterday. I believe I managed to get rid of that error by visiting the *Pricing & Distribution* section, doing small change there and saving it. Now the error is gone and I can save changes to In-App item.

Comment: It should be the `Managed Google Play` option.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue this morning and now it's working. Might have just been a bug. I'd check again now.

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved. I think issue from google side, checked last night. Now i can add products and purchase verify also resolved. I am unable to understand why there is no notice etc. from google, that issue happens.

Comment: facing verify purchase failed issue again :(

Answer (score 0):

I enabled `Managed Google Play` option in `Pricing & distribution` page under `Store presence` section and that did the trick.